# Alternate for retrywhen which is depreciated

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Below is my code to retry the http request on transient error. My code is working fine as excepted.

But I'm seeing that **retryWhen** is depreciated, can any one help me resolve this?

```
private retryRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let ok: string;
    const started = Date.now(); 
   
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(event => ok = event instanceof HttpResponse ? 'succeeded' : 'failed'),
      retryWhen(error => error.pipe(concatMap((error, count) => {
        ok = 'failed';
        if (count <= this.retryCount && this.isRetry(error)) {
          return of(error);
        }
        return this.handleResponseError(error, request, next);
      }),
        delay(this.retryWaitMilliSeconds),
        tap(err => console.log("Retrying...", err)))
      ),
      finalize(() => {
        this.consoleLogRequestTime(started, ok, request);
      }));
  }
```

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/RetryConfig

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen#deprecation-notes) state, you can instead use `retry` with it's `delay` option:

`retryWhen(func);` becomes

```
retry({
  delay: func
});
```